# Manipulate SVG with javascript?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

How do I control SVG in the following code? It's a JS code that should rotate the earth SVG around the sun SVG. My only problem, I've never worked with SVG in combination with JS before? Once I know how to rotate the earth svg, Ill figure out how to do those other planets, so just ignore those other ones.

My svgs:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 1000 600">
  <style>
    .st0{fill:#FFFF00;} .st1{fill:#808080;} .st2{fill:#EA9C4E;} .st3{fill:#3FA9F5;} .st4{fill:#F15A24;} .st5{fill:#DDC966;} .st6{fill:#A566C6;} .st7{fill:#3D9EC9;} .st8{fill:#2C709B;}
  </style>
  <circle id="Sun" cx="496.3" cy="300.4" r="45.2" class="st0"/>
  <circle id="Mercury" cx="423.6" cy="300.8" r="5.8" class="st1"/>
  <circle id="Venus" cx="576.8" cy="250.7" r="10.3" class="st2"/>
  <circle id="Earth" cx="386.2" cy="357.4" r="11" class="st3"/>
  <circle id="Mars" cx="628.8" cy="360.7" r="8.2" class="st4"/>
  <circle id="Jupiter" cx="505.9" cy="509.8" r="19.6" class="st5"/>
  <circle id="Saturn" cx="402.1" cy="156.8" r="14.2" class="st6"/>
  <circle id="Uranus" cx="235.9" cy="265.9" r="7" class="st7"/>
  <circle id="Neptune" cx="737.7" cy="310.1" r="9" class="st8"/>
</svg>
```

And my rotation JS code:

```
<script>  
    function rotate_point(pointX, pointY, originX, originY, ang) {
        ang =  Math.PI / 180.0;
        return {
            x: Math.cos(ang) * (pointX-originX) - Math.sin(ang) * (pointY-originY) + originX ,
            y: Math.sin(ang) * (pointX-originX) + Math.cos(ang) * (pointY-originY) + originY 
        };
    }

    var Solarsystem = {
        Earth: 
        {
            render: function()
            {               
                st0(386.2,357.4,10, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);                            
            }
        }
        ,  Sun: {
            render: function(){             
                gravitySun = rotate_point();
                    st0(496.3,300.4,10, 0, 2*Math.PI, true);                        
                }
            }
        }       
            function animate()
{

        }       
         var animateInterval = setInterval(animate, 1000/60);   
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following standalone svg is derived from the sample code provided in the question and represents an animated model of the orbiting planets of the solar system (without any claim of truthfully deciding physical realities of course …). It has been tested on safari 9.1, safari 9.1.1 tech preview, and firefox 35.0.1 under mac os.

The programming model for the svg dom is conceptually equivalent to its html counterpart so the vanilla js programming is effectively equivalent in both environments. In particular, the svg dom of svg 1.1 implements all interfaces from dom level 2. [Appendix B of the W3C SVG 1.1 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/svgdom.html) provides the gory technical details ...

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Layer_1" viewBox="0 0 1000 600">
<script>  
    function rotate_point(pointX, pointY, originX, originY, ang) {
        ang =  ang * Math.PI / 180.0;
        return {
            x: Math.cos(ang) * (pointX-originX) - Math.sin(ang) * (pointY-originY) + originX ,
            y: Math.sin(ang) * (pointX-originX) + Math.cos(ang) * (pointY-originY) + originY 
        };
    } // rotate_point

    //
    // render
    // generic rendering of a unit orbital progression of a planet
    //
    function render ( planet ) {
        var x, y, x_sun, y_sun, e, c_new
            ;
        e = document.getElementById ( planet );
        x = parseFloat ( e.getAttribute ( "cx" ) );
        y = parseFloat ( e.getAttribute ( "cy" ) );
        x_sun = parseFloat ( document.getElementById ( "Sun" ).getAttribute ( "cx" ) );
        y_sun = parseFloat ( document.getElementById ( "Sun" ).getAttribute ( "cy" ) );
        c_new = rotate_point ( x, y, x_sun, y_sun, 1.0 / Solarsystem[planet].period * 2.0 );
        e.setAttribute ( "cx", c_new.x );
        e.setAttribute ( "cy", c_new.y );
    } // render       


    var Solarsystem = {
          Mercury: { period: 0.25 }
        , Venus: { period: 1.41 }
        , Earth: { period: 1.0 }
        , Mars: { period: 2.0 }
        , Jupiter: { period: 2.5 }
        , Saturn: { period: 3.5 }
        , Uranus: { period: 7.0 }
        , Neptune: { period: 5.0 }
    };

    function animate () {
        render("Mercury");
        render("Venus");
        render("Earth");
        render("Mars");
        render("Jupiter");
        render("Saturn");
        render("Uranus");
        render("Neptune");
    }       

    var animateInterval = setInterval(animate, 1000 / 60);
</script>
<style>
    .st0{fill:#FFFF00;} .st1{fill:#808080;} .st2{fill:#EA9C4E;} .st3{fill:#3FA9F5;} .st4{fill:#F15A24;} .st5{fill:#DDC966;} .st6{fill:#A566C6;} .st7{fill:#3D9EC9;} .st8{fill:#2C709B;}
</style>
  <circle id="Sun" cx="496.3" cy="300.4" r="45.2" class="st0"/>
  <circle id="Mercury" cx="423.6" cy="300.8" r="5.8" class="st1"/>
  <circle id="Venus" cx="576.8" cy="250.7" r="10.3" class="st2"/>
  <circle id="Earth" cx="386.2" cy="357.4" r="11" class="st3"/>
  <circle id="Mars" cx="628.8" cy="360.7" r="8.2" class="st4"/>
  <circle id="Jupiter" cx="505.9" cy="509.8" r="19.6" class="st5"/>
  <circle id="Saturn" cx="402.1" cy="156.8" r="14.2" class="st6"/>
  <circle id="Uranus" cx="235.9" cy="265.9" r="7" class="st7"/>
  <circle id="Neptune" cx="737.7" cy="310.1" r="9" class="st8"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Sort of off subject, isn't Venus' orbit supposed to be faster than Earth's?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. And zer00ne, yeah, Venus rotates about 1.6 times faster than earth, the code was provided so that I can adjust it myself. I don't think he really needed to worry about that kind of accuracy.